# I want to move button left-right and right-left using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am able to move button to left side but after that how i can again move it to right side.
Can i also use delay here.

Here is the code that i have tried:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      example_animate(10);


  });

  function example_animate(px) {

     $('#Button1').animate({
         'marginLeft': px

     });
 }
```

Comment: `example_animate(whateverWasTheOriginalMargin);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this, it is working perfectly for me, it will continuously move your element back and forth, and you can also vary animation speed.

```
function animatethis(targetElement, speed) {
        $(targetElement).animate({ marginLeft: "+=10px" },
{
    duration: speed,
    complete: function () {
        targetElement.animate({ marginLeft: "-=10px" },
        {
            duration: speed,
            complete: function () {
                animatethis(targetElement, speed);
            }
        });
    }
)};
}
```

use this to implement:

```
animatethis($('#controlid'), 1500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot answer properly without looking at your HTML and CSS but what you are doing is right. Simply call your example_animate() with a negative value

i.e.

```
example_animate(-10);
```

Or if you want to bring it to the original value (assuming originally it had 0 margin)

```
example_animate(0);
```

Note: This is probably not the best way to animate

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function takes a function that is called after the animation is complete. So you can do:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      example_animate(100);
  });

  function example_animate(px) {   
     $('#Button1').animate({
         'marginLeft': px
     }, function(){
       $('#Button1').animate({
         'marginLeft': 1
       });
     });
 }
```

http://jsbin.com/ixajol/1/edit

Answer (score -1):

Do execly the same only to the right, Its not that hard if you can make it go left.

Comment: this answer is worse than a comment.

Comment: This is not an answer. It should be a comment on the question itself. It might be obvious _to you_ but to the person asking the question, it is not obvious.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe

```
var button_init_marginLeft;
$(document).ready(function () {
   button_init_marginLeft = $('#Button1').css("marginLeft");
   example_animate(10, true);
   example_animate(null, false);
});

function example_animate(px, to_left) {
  if (to_left)
  {
    $('#Button1').animate({
      'marginLeft': px
    });
  }
  else
  {
    $('#Button1').animate({
      'marginLeft': button_init_marginLeft
    });
  }
}
```

?